# Harry Potter fanfiction where he wakes back up from death with no memories, has secret rooms locked by password

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Years ago, I read an HP fanfiction on fanfiction.net. It was really a very long, well thought out story, so I'm wondering if it didn't get published.

It started with Harry living with the Dursleys. Vernon and Dudley were abusing him (I remember him being stabbed with a fork) and they beat him to death, I'm pretty sure. Then I think the house caught fire and burned down around Harry's body and the Dursleys all died?
Harry woke up without any memories.

The story gets fuzzy in my mind here (I think I was 12-13 when I read this, so around 8 years ago) but Harry had secret rooms. I think he had a ring or a necklace or something that held the rooms, in a way. They could only be opened with a password, which he set to be 'safehaven.' I know at one point, he meets up with Ginny and they go into his rooms and I'm pretty sure that is left to the imagination. 
I don't remember the ending at all. :(

I remember the author's name was a man's name with Roman numerals at the end.

This has been in my mind for years! I have tried to find it before, to no success.

Comment: Do you know what it was rated by chance?

Comment: Searching [either the site](https://www.fanfiction.net/search.php?keywords=safehaven&type=story&match=any&formatid=any&sort=0&genreid1=0&genreid2=0&characterid1=0&characterid2=0&characterid3=0&characterid4=0&words=0&ready=1&categoryid=0#) or Google "site:" search yields nothing useful.

Comment: Oy. I think I should stop trying now. "Sirius has a problem with a fork and Remus solves it".

Comment: @DVK Oh man, creating vague Harry Potter Fanfiction Identification questions just to force people to read listings of Harry Potter fanfiction sounds like a great prank.

Answer (score 21):

Through some sleuth Googling, I did find this (although I'm kinda wishing I hadn't! :P). I found it by searching for "fanfiction harry potter 'safehaven' password", where it is the second result (this question is the first).

The story is called [Strengthening Wounds](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2290985/1/Strengthening-Wounds), and is written by user [Louis IX](https://www.fanfiction.net/u/682104/Louis-IX) on [FanFiction.net](https://www.fanfiction.net/).

***It started with Harry living with the Dursleys. Vernon and Dudley were abusing him (I remember him being stabbed with a fork) and they beat him to death, I'm pretty sure.***

> "Come on... sonny! Let's give... the freak... a last run-down." The
>   underlying tone was clear, and frightened Petunia Dursley. [...]
>   "...do you think I can touch the heart with a fork? Ah, missed, bad
>   luck..." [...] It was a long time until both Dursley males turn back
>   into the living room, a demented gleam in their eyes, and blood on
>   their clothes and hands." - Chapter 6, Global Destruction

***Then I think the house caught fire and burned down around Harry's body
and the Dursleys all died? Harry woke up without any memories.***

> "As soon as the lid opened, the liquid fire engulfed the corridor,
>   setting fire to everything." - Chapter 6, Global Destruction
>
> "He sensed something on his right hand, and looked down. A signet ring
>   with "G/S" on it. That sealed it, he was convinced now. His name was
>   Gabriel Swift. What little was left of Harry Potter left the shoddy
>   area towards the city, and a new life." - Chapter 7, Mourning and the
>   Afterlife

***The story gets fuzzy in my mind here (I think I was 12-13 when I read this, so around 8 years ago)***

The fic was posted in 2005, ten years ago. (FYI, it's rated M - 16+ unverified, with content suitable for mature teens and older.)

***but Harry had secret rooms. I think he had a ring or a necklace or something that held the rooms, in a way. They could only be opened with a password, which he set to be 'safehaven.'***

> "His heart beating at his discovery, he braced himself, and, still
>   holding the book, spoke aloud. 'Safehaven.'" - Chapter 14, Surprise,
>   Surprise
>
> "He found himself on a bed, panting. His heart beating fearfully, he
>   rose and started to explore his surroundings. It was quick, because
>   the place was small. Small, and without any door or window. He started
>   to panic, and scanned the set of rooms rapidly." - Chapter 15, Room
>   Service

***I know at one point, he meets up with Ginny and they go into his rooms and I'm pretty sure that is left to the imagination.***

I'll leave you to find that passage, I think.

***I remember the author's name was a man's name with Roman numerals at the end.***

Louis IX.

Comment: Well done. And I commend you for soldiering through enough of the fix to provide the quotes.